# db2 DDL failing - could not figure out why

Tags: db2, ddl

Trying to execute following DDL on db2 10 for Windows, but could not figure out what is the error. Can someone please help me? thanks

```
CREATE TABLE DST_STG.TEMP1 (
te VARCHAR(50), t integer );
```

I keep seeing following error :

```
CREATE TABLE DST_STG.TEMP1 (
te VARCHAR(50), t integer )


An unexpected token "(" was found following "TEMP1 ( 
te VARCHAR".  Expected tokens may include:  "CHARACTER".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.18.60



Elapsed Time:  0 hr, 0 min, 0 sec, 0 ms.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometime you figure out problem after posting it out here. Looks like some funny character was there in between causing the problem. When tried to paste is on command line, character was visible otherwise it was not visible on notepad++ as well ( after enabling show all characters). I tried copying and pasting it over here character was not visible hence putting the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the world of character encoding.  Have fun!